# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value?

Tags: c#, mysql

Galera tenho esse código de UPDATE pra fazer, onde ele soma o valor anterior da coluna (`valor_abertura`) com um que vem do `UPDATE`, mas ele da o erro:

```
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value.
```

os valores estão em `decimal` no `MySQL` e no `C#`.

```
commad.CommandText = "UPDATE pdv_historico SET sangria = @sangria , 
valor_abertura = @valor_abertura + '" + reforco +"' 
ORDER BY idpdv_historico DESC LIMIT 1";

commad.Parameters.AddWithValue("sangria", sangria);                                    
commad.Parameters.AddWithValue("valor_abertura", reforco);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere commad.CommandText para `UPDATE pdv_historico SET sangria = @sangria , valor_abertura = @valor_abertura ORDER BY idpdv_historico DESC LIMIT 1`, Uma vez que sangria e valor_abertura é que são adicionados como parâmetros.

Se pretende `adicionar` o valor de `reforco` ao valor que está em `valor_abertura` na base de dados deverá ser `UPDATE pdv_historico SET sangria = @sangria , valor_abertura = valor_abertura + @valor_abertura ORDER BY idpdv_historico DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Opa muito obrigador, deu certo agora tvdias.